# Javascript not working in IE, but all other browsers are working fine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I've got some testimonials that cycle on my home page and the code seems to be working just fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but not in IExplorer.  I'm running IE 9.  I'd appreciate any help or insights.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="quotes">
    <div id="tst">
        <div id="quote"></div>
    </div>
    <br><span></span>
</div>
<div class="comment"><strong>
    <div id="tstperson"></div></strong>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quote=new Array();
      quote[0]="An essential tool in preparation for any show. Valuable time is saved, refining vocals much earlier in the process.";
      quote[1]="Invaluable for learning vocal lines! A brilliantly simple and easy to use interface that saved me hours of time.";
      quote[2]="MixMyPart saved us almost a week of rehersal time. A brilliant invention. Singers come in less nervous and more focused.";
    <!--   quote[3]="An invaluble tool for learning vocal lines! Brilliantly simple and easy to use interface that saved me hours of time.";  
    -->

    var quoteperson=new Array();
      quoteperson[0]="Bob Foster, <font color=\"ffffff\">Music Director</font>";
      quoteperson[1]="Liam Tobin, <font color=\"ffffff\">Actor</font>";
      quoteperson[2]="Shawn Wright, <font color=\"ffffff\">Actor</font>";
    <!--   quoteperson[3]="Liam Tobin, <a href=\"website.html\" target=\"_blank\">website.org</a>";    
    -->

    var speed=7000;
    var q=Math.floor(Math.random()*quote.length)

    function showQuote() {
         document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML="&ldquo;"+quote[q]+"&rdquo;";
         document.getElementById("tstperson").innerHTML=quoteperson[q]; 
         q++;
    if(q==quote.length) {
         q=0;
      }
    }
    showQuote();
    setInterval('showQuote()',speed);
</script>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What's it doing?

Answer (score 6):

```
<!-- -->
```

is NOT a valid JavaScript comment.  Use /*  */ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment markup is not valid for javascript.  Revise your script as follows, and it works properly in IE:

```
var quote=new Array();
  quote[0]="An essential tool in preparation for any show. Valuable time is saved, refining vocals much earlier in the process.";
  quote[1]="Invaluable for learning vocal lines! A brilliantly simple and easy to use interface that saved me hours of time.";
  quote[2]="MixMyPart saved us almost a week of rehersal time. A brilliant invention. Singers come in less nervous and more focused.";
// quote[3]="An invaluble tool for learning vocal lines! Brilliantly simple and easy to use interface that saved me hours of time.";  

var quoteperson=new Array();
  quoteperson[0]="Bob Foster, <font color=\"ffffff\">Music Director</font>";
  quoteperson[1]="Liam Tobin, <font color=\"ffffff\">Actor</font>";
  quoteperson[2]="Shawn Wright, <font color=\"ffffff\">Actor</font>";
// quoteperson[3]="Liam Tobin, <a href=\"website.html\" target=\"_blank\">website.org</a>";
```